# Instamojo PG in android studio with firebase backend

Tags: android, firebase, payment-gateway, instamojo

I am trying to use instamojo PG [1] to accept payments on my android app. For the backend I am using firebase,

Devsupport AI Android integration it is asking me URL for the access token

https://docs.instamojo.com/page/android-sdk

How do I create an endpoint in firebase to create this access token ?

Comment: you need to host a piece of code that gives access token as explained here. https://docs.instamojo.com/v1.1/page/devsupport-ai-android-integration#other-back-end-technologies

Read access_token and prepend your environment to it.

E.g if you are testing on Test environment, access token should look like this: testtyDkRjkirDEmF4PP8AHNrS3NnGwrt6

If you are on Production environment, access token should look like this:
productiontyDkRjkirDEmF4PP8AHNrS3NnGwrt6

Host your script on server, keep it's URL ready and proceed to the bot for Android integration.